# fail2ban not working or not ban ip after login fail

Tags: fail2ban

i try fail2ban on my servers atleast 10 times, most of the time it not ban ip

In my jail.local

```
[ssh]

enabled  = true
port     = ssh,some_port_number
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 2
bantime = 180
```

and on my server i install fail2ban and configure using this in my sh file

```
sudo apt-get -y install fail2ban
sudo cp custom_jail.local /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
sudo service fail2ban restart
```

and also i set **RepeatedMsgReduction off** in rsyslog.conf
and run this *service rsyslog restart*

after ssh login fail (maxretry limit ) i am still able to login it not ban my ip

**auth.log**

```
Jun 20 21:17:29 localhost sshd[4705]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=ip  user=username
Jun 20 21:17:32 localhost sshd[4705]: Failed password for username from ip port 36472 ssh2
Jun 20 21:17:36 localhost sshd[4705]: Failed password for username from ip port 36472 ssh2
Jun 20 21:17:41 localhost sshd[4705]: Failed password for username from ip port 36472 ssh2
Jun 20 21:17:41 localhost sshd[4705]: Connection closed by ip [preauth]
```

**fail2ban.log**

```
2015-06-20 21:15:07,186 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'ssh' stopped
2015-06-20 21:15:07,209 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'ssh-ddos' stopped
2015-06-20 21:15:07,210 fail2ban.server : INFO   Exiting Fail2ban
2015-06-20 21:15:07,790 fail2ban.server : INFO   Changed logging target to /var/log/fail2ban.log for Fail2ban v0.8.11
2015-06-20 21:15:07,791 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Creating new jail 'ssh'
2015-06-20 21:15:07,821 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'ssh' uses pyinotify
2015-06-20 21:15:07,846 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Initiated 'pyinotify' backend
2015-06-20 21:15:07,848 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Added logfile = /var/log/auth.log
2015-06-20 21:15:07,849 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Set maxRetry = 2
2015-06-20 21:15:07,850 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Set findtime = 600
2015-06-20 21:15:07,850 fail2ban.actions: INFO   Set banTime = 180
2015-06-20 21:15:07,884 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Creating new jail 'ssh-ddos'
2015-06-20 21:15:07,884 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'ssh-ddos' uses pyinotify
2015-06-20 21:15:07,891 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Initiated 'pyinotify' backend
2015-06-20 21:15:07,893 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Added logfile = /var/log/auth.log
2015-06-20 21:15:07,894 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Set maxRetry = 2
2015-06-20 21:15:07,894 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Set findtime = 600
2015-06-20 21:15:07,895 fail2ban.actions: INFO   Set banTime = 180
2015-06-20 21:15:07,901 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'ssh' started
2015-06-20 21:15:07,907 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'ssh-ddos' started
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the point why fail2ban not ban ip

previously after editing  **jail.local**  i **restart fail2ban**

but now i first **stop fail2ban** and then **start fail2ban**  this works for me

I am using Ubuntu 14.04